# Invalid Message Format on Postgresql using Docker

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker

Don't know if it is a docker related problem, or a postgres one.

I'm having problems when executing "long" queries, such as:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES
(1111111, 1111, 'whatever'),
(1111112, 2222, 'any other'),
...
(1111113, 3333, 'something else');
```

with 200+ lines.

The 209 lines give a string length of 8746 characters (not that much, I know, although it is more than 8KB (+16 KB as Unicode).

Unable to execute via psql, pgAdmin or using a .NET application.

1. Is there any limit on SQL strings? (using local postgres works just fine)
2. Any kind of configuration that needs to be hacked?

More Info:
If I divide the sql into 209 instructions, as:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (1111111, 1111, 'whatever');
INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (1111112, 2222, 'any other');
...
INSERT INTO schema.table VALUES (1111113, 3333, 'something else');
```

the query executes just fine (no problem with the size, even if it is a single string with all the instructions

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the connection to Postgres.  The database supports queries longer than 8K.

Comment: Would think so, but the strange thing is the query executes fine if separated into smaller chunks.
Maybe it has something to do with too many values?
When dividing in 2 parts (approx 100 rows each) the query also executes fine.

The main issue is that I intend to use NPGSQL and EF CORE to do the DB INSERTS, as such I would prefer to send it as one instruction only.

Comment: You should include the Postgres error message in the question, if it is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback.

After some more digging, I found out the problem is on the docker for windows beta.

Somehow the connection through the exposed port (localhost:port).

More details can be found here: https://forums.docker.com/t/localhost-port-forwarding-causing-invalid-sql/17719.

Thanks for the interest

Comment: Later you should accept (click green checkmark by) your own answer. That's how we mark a question solved.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about it.